# mysql join only if a field has a particular value

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to fetch a table on certain conditions with join. My table is:

```
        tab_registrations
    --------------------------------------------
    reg_id |familyid| familyname  | parent_id |
           |        |             |           |
    -------|--------|-------------|-----------|
    1      |  2     |   null      | null      |
    -------|--------|-------------|-----------|
    2      | others |    abc      | 3         |
    -------|--------|-------------|-----------|
    3      | 3      |   null      |   null    |
    -------|--------|-------------|-----------|
    4      | others |  def        |   2       |
    -------|--------|-------------|-----------|

    tab_family
    -------------------------------------
    family_id | family_name | parent_id |
              |             |           |
    -------------------------------------
    1         | tyu         |   0       |
    -------------------------------------
    2         | xyz         |   1       |
    -------------------------------------
    3         | mno         |   2       |
    -------------------------------------
```

I want to join these tables on:

1. if tab_registrations.family not equal to null, then select corresponding parent_id from tab_family

   ```
   SELECT tab_registration.*,tab_family.family_id,tab_family.parent_id
    FROM `tab_registration`
    join tab_family  on tab_registration.family_id = tab_family.family_id
    WHERE reg_id = 1
   ```
2. if tab_registrations.family is equal to 'others', then select tab_registrations.familyname and tab_registrations.parent_id

When I try the above query if tab_registrations.family = 'others', no rows fetched

How can I achieve this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is ```family_id``` in ```tab_registration```. What you are trying to match exactly.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: family_id is familyid in tab_registrations.. see my edit

Comment: @tim I want the whole `tab_registrations`. I want to join only if tab_registrations.familyid is not 'others'.

Comment: ```SELECT tab_registration.*,tab_family.family_id,tab_family.parent_id
 FROM `tab_registration`
 join tab_family  on tab_registration.familyid = tab_family.family_id
 WHERE tab_registration.reg_id = 1 AND tab_registration.familyname IS NOT NULL```. Try this.

Comment: use left join in query so you will get tab_registrations.family = 'others' records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to `LEFT JOIN` with the condition that `tab_registration.familyid` is not equal to `others`. Also, you can use conditional `CASE..WHEN` statements to get the `familyname` and `parent_id` values.

```
SELECT tr.*,
       CASE WHEN tr.familyid = 'others' THEN tr.familyname 
            ELSE tf.family_name
       END AS familyname, 
       CASE WHEN tr.familyid = 'others' THEN tr.parent_id 
            ELSE tf.parent_id
       END AS parent_id
FROM tab_registration tr
LEFT JOIN tab_family tf
  ON tr.family_id = tf.family_id AND 
     tr.familyid <> 'others'
WHERE tr.reg_id = 1
```

For multi-table queries, it if preferable to use Aliasing for code clarity and readability.

Comment: the query is working..!! But when `tr.familyid = 'others'`, the result contains `tr.familyname` twice

Comment: @Aishwaryas does it affect anything ? The problem is with `tr.*`. Do you want to fetch all the columns of `tab_registration` table or replace them wtih `tab_family` if `familyid` is not equal to `others`

Comment: yes.. I got it..! You are again my day saver @MadhurBhaiya

Answer (score -2):

may be useful this query

```
SELECT tr.*,tf.family_id,tf.parent_id,
 IF(tr.familyid='others',tr.familyname,tf.family_name) as fname
 IF(tr.familyid='others',tr.parent_id,tf.parent_id) as parentId
 FROM `tab_registration` tr
 left join tab_family tf on tr.family_id = tf.family_id
```